# A windows box network port is accessible within LAN but not through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a windows box running apache. Its port 80 is accessible from any computer in the LAN. But not accessible to computers connected through VPN. The firewall on the box is set to allow TCP/80 for 'public'.

I am not sure where the connection is getting blocked. Can someone, kindly, help how to troubleshoot?

Comment: What IP are the users accessing?  Is it your VPN server's IP?  Is your Apache listening for connections on it?

Comment: It sounds like the router will not let you bridge traffic between the VPN and the internal network. Try accessing port 80 via the router's public IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone, kindly, help how to troubleshoot?

First of all, to wipe out the possibility which firewall may cause this issue. please turn off the firewall and try again.

If it doesn't work, we need to make sure that there is a valid route for client to access your Windows box. Please try to ping the Windows box from the VPN client.

If the ping successes, it means something between the VPN client and the Windows box blocks the HTTP message.

If the ping fails, please try to perform a network capture on VPN server and the Windows box to check which device drops the packets.

Comment: Ping fails too... seems IT temporarily blocked VPN traffic to the subnet.